# Is "our very next work" a common phrase?

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context

In order to point to our next work that planned to be done in the near future, is it common to use ***"our very next work"***? Googling could not provide reliable help, by the way!

Comment: The are usage instances of “very next work” in Google Books. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=very+next+work&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvery%20next%20work%3B%2Cc0 What is your concern?

Comment: @user2922582, Since the usage is very limited, it seems to be uncommon!

Comment: Well, nonetheless it is correct and clear. The sources from Ngram are reliable, so I don’t see why you shouldn’t use such expression.

Comment: What sort of work? In such a usage, *work* is normally a discrete piece of work and generally artistic like a musical composition or a sculpture. It wouldn't normally be used about bringing a database into service, for example. You have used "meaning in context" but not provided any.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, I mean a research study.

Comment: There is also "very next **work day**" in that mix.  The concern with "very next work" isn't so much technical grammaticality as it is pomposity.

Answer (score 1):

In the (somewhat limited) context you give (which I take to mean "*the next task to be performed*"), *no*, I don't think "*our very next work*" is a common phrase (it certainly sounds "wrong" to my Br.E ears).

As [Andrew Leach](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/18696/andrew-leach) says in a comment, that phrase (or, at least, "*very next work*") would be more common of a book, composition or other "artistic" work, and – to my mind – would generally be used when talking about works that have already been produced, rather than tasks yet to be done. This is borne out by a number of the [Ngram searches](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=very+next+work&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvery%20next%20work%3B%2Cc0) that [user2922582](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/159691/user2922582) provided:

> Then, after that, *my very next work* was Bulletproof Monk
>
> This appears, among other strange things, from *his very next work*. " The Fear of God"
>
> The *very next work* published in the Kierkegaardian authorship

As an alternative, I would probably just go with either **our [very] next piece of work** or **our [very] next task**. In both cases, I would say the "*very*" is somewhat optional, and I would probably not use it.